# how Ajax calls url with particular div id

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

Hi I am trying to retrieve data without page refresh  see my ajax code

```
function ajaxCall() {
 $.ajax({
    type: "post",
    cache: false,
    url: "test2.php", 
    success: (function (result) {
        $("#user2").html(result);
          })
     })
 };

  ajaxCall(); 
  setInterval(ajaxCall, (2 * 1000));
```

**in Test2.php**

```
     <div id="user2">
     Data loads here 

     </div>
```

with this code loads  the entire page, but I need only  div content Please help me Thanks in advance

Comment: Any reason you are using `post` instead of `get`?

Comment: @SouvikGhosh no i was  just tried with post method

Comment: Try with `get` and see.

Comment: @SouvikGhosh same result no use

Answer (score 0):

Try this one instead-

```
function ajaxCall() {
$.ajax({
   type: "get",
   cache: false,
   url: "test2.php", 
   success: (function (result) {
       $("#user2").html(result);
       $("#user2").load(location.href + " #user2");
         })
    })
};

ajaxCall(); 
setInterval(ajaxCall, (2 * 1000));
```

You may also try the second approach-

```
(function ajaxCall(){
    $.get('test2.php')
    .done(function(data){
        $('#user2').html(data);
    })
    .always(function(){
        setInterval(ajaxCall, (2 * 1000));
    });
}());
```

Comment: Check the updated answer I edited. If still doesn't work, try `post` instead of `get`.

Comment: No friend  same  result , Do you know  any other way load data

Comment: Please check what is the data inside `result`.

Comment: Yes. Data where inside Div ?

Comment: No. Put an `alert(result);` before you update the div to see the data inside result. I have added another approach, check that.

Comment: With out $("#user2").append(result);   
     $("#user2").load(location.href + " #user2");
  alert(1) working , not loading data with out refresh

Answer (score 0):

You need to prevent the default behavior, All that is needed to make this work is a return false; from the handler function.

return false from within a jQuery event handler is effectively the same as calling both e.preventDefault and e.stopPropagation.

And it is better to use get request.

your code should be looks like:

```
function ajaxCall() {
 $.ajax({
    type: "get",
    cache: false,
    url: "test2.php", 
    success: (function (result) {
        $("#user2").html(result);
          })
     })
    return false;
 };

  ajaxCall(); 
  setInterval(ajaxCall, (2 * 1000));
```

Comment: Loading entire page(url:test2.php)

Comment: Then is this all of your code, my answer should work.

Answer (score 0):

You can test This Code.

```
    function ajaxCall() {
        $("#whereYouWantToShow").load("test2.php div#user2");
    };

    ajaxCall();

    setInterval(ajaxCall, (2 * 1000));
```

Comment: I have tried this way  its works only   1 (qid) i have multiple qids  Note:qid means query id   how to load data all queries with out page refresh

Comment: you can generate all result inside a div and call this div. like
 <div id="queryResultList">result 1<br> result 2</div>

Comment: my question How to append qid

Comment: Where you want to append??

Comment: ("div1").load("url div1"); Betwen this append qid

Comment: you want previous data will be same and append new data??

Comment: if you create all result in your {url page} you don't need to append anything. because when load() function call this will remove previous data and show all data from your {url page}
jsut try to use like this ('div1').load("url div2");

Comment: Yes previous data will be same and append new data

Comment: you can follow my previous comment. because if you use ajax. then after reloading browser, all data will be removed. so just follow my previous comment.

Comment: i have tried with this one           $("#user2").load("test2.php #loadcomm"); no resultes

Comment: show me the full code please. you checked my previous code so it must work.

Comment: ok, how you get $d['qid'],$row[uid]  value in your page?? just confirm first if you run test2.php directly is there generate anything or not?

Comment: Yes, $d  we define that  getting queries in same page code was ok  and comments also ok but we need with out page refresh

Comment: hi you use double m in this line 
$("#user2").load("test2.php #loadcomm");
but in test2.php only one m for #loadcom

Comment: the result was same only one query loads data with out page refresh

Comment: if you query not generate multiple result in test2.php then it will show only one result if generate multiple result then will show multiple result. so check you test2.php

Comment: check my simple code for test2.php <div id="user2">
    <div id="loadcom">

        <?php 
    echo "<ul>"; 
        $i=1;
        while($i<10){
            echo "<li>";
            echo $i."</li><br>";
            $i++;
        }
    echo "</ul>";
        
        ?>
    </div>

</div>

Comment: please see https://pastebin.com/jcBP5Qyv insert into database working fine using ajax